# Print all content of a paged post

Tags: posts, paged

is it possible to print a complete post that has a number of pages?

I'm working on a website that the client would like users to be able to print an article. The problem I have right now is when an article has a number of pages, by using WordPress's `<!--nextpage-->`.

Say an article has the content split into 3 pages. Is there a way when printing the page to have all the content from those 3 pages displayed?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Wellcome to WPSE. When asking in this site,it is good practice to show the effort you have done already, working or not.

Answer (score 0):

One way to acheive this is to create a filter on `the_content();`

This will completely stop the `<!--nextpage-->` shortcode from working wherever `the_content();` is called in your theme - i.e. on all posts

You can add the filter by adding this to your functions file:

```
function remove_page_144242($content){
    global $post;
    // Accesses the post content while unformatted
    $content = $post->post_content;
    // Find the nextpage shortcode
    $find = '<!--nextpage-->';
    //Replace it with nothing
    $replace = '';
    // Perform the replace
    $content = str_ireplace($find,$replace,$content);
    // Return the final content
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_page_144242', 1);
```

If you're looking for a solution on a single post basis or on a template then you can do something similar. By first pulling back the unformatted content and doing a replace. Something like this could possibly be placed in template file specifically for a post

```
// (While in the loop)
// Make sure we can access $post
global $post;
// Access the post content unformatted
$content = $post->post_content;
// Find the nextpage shortcode
$find = '<!--nextpage-->';
//Replace it with nothing
$replace = '';
// Perform the replace
$content = str_ireplace($find,$replace,$content);
// Echo the final result
echo $content;
```

**EDIT**: Apologies the last approach will not perform actions such as shortcodes in the content